# the Binary Bomb Phase 5

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm currently working on the binary bomb lab and I'm very confused. I tried asking my friends and searching online but it seems like that my bomb is different.

```html
Dump of assembler code for function phase_5:
   0x08048d7e <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x08048d7f <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048d81 <+3>: push   %edi
   0x08048d82 <+4>: push   %esi
   0x08048d83 <+5>: push   %ebx
=> 0x08048d84 <+6>: sub    $0x1c,%esp
   0x08048d87 <+9>: mov    0x8(%ebp),%ebx
   0x08048d8a <+12>: mov    %ebx,(%esp)
   0x08048d8d <+15>: call   0x8048f10 <string_length>
   0x08048d92 <+20>: cmp    $0x6,%eax
   0x08048d95 <+23>: je     0x8048d9c <phase_5+30>
   0x08048d97 <+25>: call   0x8049016 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048d9c <+30>: mov    $0x0,%edx
   0x08048da1 <+35>: mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x08048da6 <+40>: mov    $0x8049f80,%ecx
   0x08048dab <+45>: movsbl (%ebx,%eax,1),%esi
   0x08048daf <+49>: and    $0xf,%esi
   0x08048db2 <+52>: add    (%ecx,%esi,4),%edx
   0x08048db5 <+55>: add    $0x1,%eax
   0x08048db8 <+58>: cmp    $0x6,%eax
   0x08048dbb <+61>: jne    0x8048dab <phase_5+45>
   0x08048dbd <+63>: cmp    $0x37,%edx
   0x08048dc0 <+66>: je     0x8048dc7 <phase_5+73>
   0x08048dc2 <+68>: call   0x8049016 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048dc7 <+73>: add    $0x1c,%esp
   0x08048dca <+76>: pop    %ebx
   0x08048dcb <+77>: pop    %esi
   0x08048dcc <+78>: pop    %edi
   0x08048dcd <+79>: pop    %ebp
   0x08048dce <+80>: ret
```

I believe that my result should be six numbers that sum up to be 37.This is what I got from gdb

```html
(gdb) x/15wx 0x8049f80
0x8049f80 <array.2963>: 0x00000002 0x0000000a 0x00000006 0x00000001
0x8049f90 <array.2963+16>: 0x0000000c 0x00000010 0x00000009 0x00000003
0x8049fa0 <array.2963+32>: 0x00000004 0x00000007 0x0000000e 0x00000005
0x8049fb0 <array.2963+48>: 0x0000000b 0x00000008 0x0000000f
```

Can someone please explain this to me? I'll really appreciate it.

Comment: You need to pick 6 numbers from the array that sum up to `0x37`. Then pick a printable character for each one that has the appropriate index as the low 4 bits. For example, `0x37 = 5*0x9 + 0xa`, `0x9` has index `6` and `0xa` has index `1` so a working code should be `666661`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Jester!